# Yandex Market жутко тормозит

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

Добавил библиотеку `Yandex market` в проект, `gradle` успешно все собрал, но есть две проблемы!

1. карты очень неохотно срабатывают на зум и свайпы, загружается подлагивая, железо не самое плохое HTC One m7.
2. предпросмотр лэйаута выдает "

   > Rendering problems. The following classes could not be instantiated: -ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView

И далее идет стак трейс с `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.storage.StorageManager.getVolumeList(StorageManager.java:872)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.getExternalDirs(Environment.java:83)
at android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState(Environment.java:636)
at ah.d(Unknown Source)
at ah.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapController.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapSurfaceView.init(Unknown Source)
at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapSurfaceView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:168)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.parseInclude(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:197)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:879)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:831)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:362)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: На предпросмоторщик вообще внимания не обращайте. Он работает нормально только для простейших разметок типа картинки в контейнере. Всё что сложнее обычно не работает.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, а как быть с медленной работой карт?

Comment: Про карты, к сожалению, не знаю - не работал с ними(. Попробуйте разметку в вопрос добавить - может она у вас перегружена и оттого и ормозит

Comment: там пустой лэйаут с mapview во весь экран, ни чего лишнего

Comment: Нашли решение медленной карты?

Comment: Увы не нашел, использовал вместо этого OSMDroid  там яндекс карты тоже можно подключить и работают там они гораздо лучше

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать в xml для mapView  параметр `android:tag="static"`

https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/issues/215#issuecomment-211109620